# How do I print the node add form in block.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I am using [Microblog](http://drupal.org/project/microblog). How do I print the node add form in a block?

I tried `node_add('microblog')`, but it doesn't work for me; then, I tried `drupal_get_form('microblog_node_form')`, but I am still getting nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could look at the [Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/formblock) module, which will allow you to easily create blocks with node add forms for your content types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i won't use a module for a single task.

Answer (score 3):

The drupal_get_form approach is correct. Make sure you use

```
print drupal_get_form(....
```

Edit:

Take a look at function `node_add()`. 
You also need a `$node` parameter for this form. So like

```
<?php
  global user; 
  $node = array('uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''), 'type' => 'foo', 'language' => '');     
  print drupal_get_form('foo_node_form', $node);
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, i didnt forgot about print, but still it prints nothing. When im firebugging over microblog form i see that:

Comment: <form class="microblog-node-form" id="node-form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/microblog/1">
</form>

Comment: Take a look at function node_add(). You also need a $node parameter for this form.

Comment: This is the correct answer for D7: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7740337/208341

Answer (score 2):

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

$form = node_add('nodetype');

print drupal_render($form);
```

Comment: This code is correct; never call `drupal_render()` as `drupal_render(node_add())`.

Answer (score 1):

Placing this in a block works for me:

```
<?php
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  print drupal_render(node_add('CONTENT_TYPE'));
?>
```

Comment: This code doesn't work, since `drupal_render()` expects a parameter passed by reference, while `node_add()` doesn't return a reference. With PHP 5.3, this causes an error.